# How to replace raster values in one Raster with another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, raster-calculator

I have two raster files in ArcGIS 10.1, raster 1 and raster 2 all with values and similar spatial resolutions, and overlay in some areas.

I want to replace values in raster 1 with those in raster 2 where there is an overlay.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use raster calculator, try this:

`Con(IsNull(raster1),raster2, raster1)`

meaning that if raster1 has no value, it will use the value of raster2, otherwise it will use the value of raster1. Under the `Enviroments...` tab you can select your desired extent of the output raster. This will only work, if your raster1 has a lot of gaps.

---

However, I guess the **best solution** would be to use the `mosaic to new raster` tool in your `Data Management` toolbox, since you only want to replace values and not perform any other operation. Look at the following example:
[image: mosaicraster]

Make sure the `Mosaic operator` is set to your raster2, so that values from it will be used instead of raster1.